# BufferedWriter only works the first time

Tags: java

I have a simple server-client program that takes info from the client and passes it to the server. The messages are passed through a DatagramSocket. The server then takes the message and writes it to a text file.

My initial message works fine(gets printed to the file). However, if I run the client again then the new message does not get written to the file. I have to RESTART the server for the message to be printed again.

I have an arrayCopy method that copies two arrays and puts it into a larger array.

CLIENT

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter Username");
    BufferedReader usernameInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    // Get the Username
    String username = directoryInput.readLine();
    byte[] usrname = username.getBytes();

    //Copy Username to Array
    byte[] tempArray = copyarray(packetheader, usrname);

    buffer = tempArray;
    mypacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, IPaddr, 40000);
    clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    clientSocket.send(mypacket);
```

Server

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String Database;
    textfile = "C:\\textfile.txt";
    DatagramSocket serverSock = new DatagramSocket(40000);

    byte[] rbuf = new byte[97];

    DatagramPacket recievedPacket = new DatagramPacket(rbuf, rbuf.length);
    serverSock.receive(recievedPacket);
    String byteToString = new String(recievedPacket.getData(), 0, recievedPacket.getLength(), "US- ASCII");
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(textfile);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(byteToString);
    out.close
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. Added a code snippet. I'd prefer not to post my entire code publicly at this time for various reasons. Let me know if you need more then what's given.

Comment: Is the text file same for all clients or a unique one is created for each client?

Comment: Without seeing your code, hard to say, but I suspect there's something wrong with the server listening for and setting up the connections.

Comment: @user1068744 - sorry, but without more context, all we can say is that "you're doing it wrong" - which is admittedly not very helpful.

Comment: I guess your server listening code is not right. Add it here. And I think you should call `clientSocket.close()` on your client before exitting.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I added the code to the client and server. The client class has more code but those do not directly involve dealing with the sockets(they are for the menu interface of the program)

Comment: The Server code doesn't have any loops!  After one connection it will call out.close() and the fall off the end of main (and stop), right?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Does this mean I need to implement it as a multithreaded server?

Comment: First get it working with a loop.  If the incoming messages are short and don't come too often, you can probably get away with a single thread.

Comment: Im confused as to what I need to make the loop condition. I've tried to do a while(!(receivedpacket.equalto(null))) but that causes the same line to be written more than once

Comment: The posted code does not compile. It is better to create a SSCCE http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want, what you need is a loop that allows you to read the next package, and the next and so on.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String textfile = "C:\\textfile.txt";
    DatagramSocket serverSock = new DatagramSocket(40000);

    byte[] rbuf = new byte[97];

    DatagramPacket recievedPacket = new DatagramPacket(rbuf, rbuf.length);

    while(true) {
        serverSock.receive(recievedPacket);
        String byteToString = new String(recievedPacket.getData(), 0, recievedPacket.getLength(), "US-ASCII");
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(textfile);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
        out.write(byteToString);
        out.close();
        recievedPacket.setLength(rbuf.length);
    }
}
```

However, this will overwrite the file with the new message, not append them (if that is what you wanted). If you want to store all messages you probably want to move the file creation out of the loop.

Comment: You need to re-initialize the DatagramPacket from the buffer every time around the loop. Otherwise its length keeps shrinking to the smallest datagram received so far.

Comment: I don't see that in my test (I send a message starting with length 1, and increasing) and the received message grows up to 97 in length.

Comment: With that code? Where is the DatagramPacket storing the original length? And what does a certain line in the native code do if not set the `length` member?

Comment: The doc agrees with you, but with the code posted in my answer (using print instead of storing to file) I can send messages length 1 to 97 in any order. The source of the DatagramPacket stores both the length of the message and the length of the buffer internally. Running on OSX and I don't have the source of the native receive implementation. I'll update the code, but still wonder why it works here.

Comment: Am thinking of adding a question for this, I can reuse the packet for longer messages as long as I don't explicitly set the length. And it works on OSX (Java 1.6.0_29) and Solaris (Java 1.6.0_21).